# PHP sign in user after registration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a simple login and registration form. What I'm trying to do is when a user registers, it should log them in. In order to get logged in, the user's ID that gets registered needs to be sent to the home page so the username can be displayed. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

Register:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['userID']) AND !empty($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnect, $_POST['firstName']);
        $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnect, $_POST['lastName']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnect, $_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnect, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnect, $_POST['password']);

{           // Check if data exists already in the database
            $exists = mysqli_query($dbConnect, "SELECT user_id, username, email FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND email = '$email'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($exists);

        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbemail = $row['email'];

        if ($username == $dbusername) {
            die("Username already taken.");
        }   else if ($email == $dbemail) {
            die("Email already registered.");
        }
}

        $registerUser = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName', '$username', '$email', '$password')";

{           // Select ID from registered user

        $selectID = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $selectID_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $selectID);

        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($selectID_Query);
        $userID = $fetch['user_id'];

        $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
}

        if(mysqli_query($dbConnect, $registerUser)) {
            header("Location: home.php");
        }   else {
            echo "<script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>";
        }
    }

    include "includes/head.php";
    include "includes/nav.php";
?>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="welcome-msg">
            <h1 class="huge">Registration form</h1>
            <h3 class="medium">Please fill in all the inputs</h3>

            <form id="login-form" method="post">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required>

                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required>

                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>

                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>

                <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Home:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userID']);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($tUsers_Select_Query);

include "includes/head.php";
include "includes/nav.php";

?>

    <div id="main-content">
        <h1 class="huge">Welcome back, <?php echo $row['username'] ?>!</h1>
        <a href="/lr/logout.php?logout">Logout</a>
    </div>


</body>
```

If you need any more details, please comment.

Comment: check for errors on php and queries

Comment: *It's really simple.* Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors @Fred-ii-. When I register, the user gets inserted into the database. When I get redirected to the home page, I immediately go to the index/login because the ID of the user registered isn't passed in.

Comment: @FocuZst why not use `mysqli_insert_id()`? Rather than doing another query just to get the user's ID.

Comment: @LoganWayne I assigned that function to `$_SESSION['userID']`. The ID that I get is 0.

Comment: You tried `$userID = mysqli_insert_id($con);`? And it didn't return the userid, but it the insert is successful? Is the `user_id` column PRIMARY? Auto-Increment?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I had tried `$_SESSION['userID']` and it returned 0. I just tried `$userID = mysqli_insert_id($con);` and it also returns 0. user_id is PRIMARY and is Auto-Increment.

Comment: My bad. It should be `$userID = mysqli_insert_id($dbConnect);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Check first the value of your session `$_SESSION['userID']`. Have you tried checking it in your DOM ? session values must be displayed there.

Comment: `$_SESSION['userID']` is assigned to `$userID`. That variable is assigned to the ID that is fetched from the registered user. `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'`

Comment: Have you seen the userID variable in the resource tab in developer tool?

Comment: I'm not sure of how to do that @Lucky

Comment: Press F12 if you are using chrome then click on the resource tab then try to find your PHP Session there

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @emmanuel Cant post yet I'm just new here in stack overflow trying to get reps sorry for that

Comment: @Lucky I clicked on Session storage and there's nothing there. I think I have to submit the form to be able to see something since the registering is wrapped inside an if statement that says if the submit button is clicked, register the user etc..

Comment: All of the Sessions will be stored there. Do you know how to use cookies ? I think cookies is better than sessions ;)

Comment: I'd like to focus more on using Sessions since I'm only creating this login and registration system for learning purposes.

Comment: Ohh I see . Sessions must see on the resource tab so I think there's something wrong in storing data to your session variable (Y)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to use was the function mysqli_insert_id. In the if statement that checks if the SQL command is correct, I just had to add

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = mysqli_insert_id($dbConnect);
```

If the last SQL query was an UPDATE or an INSERT query, it would return the ID. If the query was SELECT for example, it would've returned 0.

```
$registerUser = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName', '$username', '$email', '$password')";

    if(mysqli_query($dbConnect, $registerUser)) {
        $_SESSION['userID'] = mysqli_insert_id($dbConnect);
        header("Location: home.php");
    }   else {
            echo "<script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>";
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php